How do we construct the finite hyperbolic plane with 13 points?
According to Wolfram MathWorld, there are 2 non-isomorphic Steiner systems of type S(2,3,13), 1 of which is a finite hyperbolic plane. The page on a hyperbolic plane gives the following definition: lines may intersect, be parallel (i.e., approach a common ideal point), or be hyperparallel (i.e., not approach a common ideal point).
Given this information, how do we construct the S(2,3,13) Steiner system that is a hyperbolic plane?
